# Android facebook app share intent

Tags: android, facebook, share

I have been trying to share text content on Facebook share intent, and it seems like it does not let us share text for some reason. Does anyone know why they've done this? The only way to share text is to use their SDK, which takes time. Just need a justification for wasting my time. Thanks.

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            getString(R.string.share_message_facebook));

    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent,
            0);
    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
        if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("com.facebook")
                && !(app.activityInfo.name)
                        .contains("com.facebook.messenger")) {
            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                    activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
            startActivity(shareIntent);

            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It will be difficult for anyone to tell you why your "share text content" code is not working, when your question does not include that code.

Comment: Comment out the whole `PackageManager` stuff and just use your original `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` with `startActivity()`. If Facebook appears in the chooser, and choosing it works, then your problem is that your assumptions about the nature of Facebook's implementation (e.g., `com.facebook.messenger` package) are flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control), you have to give control to the users of your app. They should allow beforehand the publishing permissions if you want to publish/share on their behalf. Therefore, you should use Facebook SDK.

Comment: Thanks. now I know why I'm wasting my time... :) Although, I'm still pissed at them for making us create an app on facebook for every app we create.